# Android phone not showing transition between activites

Tags: android, animation, transition, htc-android

I've got a problem with my phone.

I am developing for Android and trying out transitions between activities, but my phone won't show them. So I downloaded the final source code of a transition tutorial:
http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-Android--Day-17%E2%80%93Animating-between-Activities

I installed it directly onto my phone, but the transitions are still not showing. I think it has to do something with the settings on my phone.
I already activated Settings > Display > Show Animations.
My Phone is a new HTC Desire X running Android 4.2.

I didn't find anything on stackoverflow or google. I hope you guys have a solution for this!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, 4 months later I got a new phone (Nexus 5) and it shows all transitions, so i guess transitions are just deactivated on the Desire X, probably because it's too slow anyways.